# Nodejs client button without redirect

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs app that acts as a remote control for Cmus music player. It uses a route for each function ie /play /next etc. This works fine, but with each button click I must call `res.redirect("index.html")` which obviously causes the page to reload. How can I perform this so that each button click is still able to send the command to the server but not reload the page?

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var Commands = require('./commands.js');
var child;

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

//Routes
app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
});

app.get('/play', function(req, res){
    // console.log(req);
    handleCommand(Commands.PAUSE);
    res.redirect("index.html");
});

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
    console.log("Server online");
    console.log(commands.NEXT);
});

function handleCommand(command) {
    child = exec(command, function (error, stdout, stderr) {
        // sys.print('Stdout ' + stdout);
        // sys.print('Stderr ' + stderr);
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
        }
    })
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Cmus Remote</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script src="client.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body id="body">
    <form action="/play">
        <input id="play" type="submit" value="&#x23ef;">
    </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a form to "submit" the button, you can attach event handlers to the button that will do a [POST](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) request without reloading the page. Then, you won't need to send any redirects at all. Since you have JQuery on the page, I'll give an example with JQuery.

Index.html

```
<button id="play">Play</button>
<!-- Other code -->

<!-- Script or external JS code -->
<script>
$('#play').click(function(){
    $.post('/play');
});
</script>
```